# Which algorithm does thrust::merge use internally?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I want to know which merge algorithm `thrust::merge` uses internally.

For example, `mgpu::merge` [(Modern GPU Merge)](https://moderngpu.github.io/merge.html) is based on [GPU Merge Path - A GPU Merging Algorithm](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2304576.2304621?casa_token=6Bdh3PuSthcAAAAA:nTRmorozJnCSRKmyMPPhP41spP2WkVO6lA2ZKeN_zAI-YUmBgVJ4Tx9rxHSwVi7xhfRUx5ErJ4qI).

Which algorithm does `thrust::merge` use and how does it differ from GPU Merge Path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, Thrust does not explicitly describe the algorithm they actually use. However, you can find the CUDA implementation [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/96a7e7b6bd99027c8450b11d02195a0209df6fa7/thrust/system/cuda/detail/merge.h#L454) and understand what the algorithm does. At the time of writing, they use a tiled-based partitioned merge.

The algorithm is divided in 3 steps:

- *partitioning*: use a binary search in shared memory to find merge path for each of thread;
- *merging*: execute an independent serial merge in each thread;
- *joining*: write data back into the global memory.

The current Thrust implementation seems to be close to the one in your provided research paper.

Comment: Unless things have changed very recently, it is a direct adaption of the Modern GPU code, as far as I recall